# How to inject production script and css to an index html with vite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, config, vite

My `vite.config.ts` is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    publicDir: './src/assets',
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: './src/main.tsx',
            name: 'index',
            fileName: 'index',
            formats: ['iife']
        }
    },
    server: {
        host: true
    }
});
```

How can I inject in the production script and css automatically in an html index?

like webpack does with html-webpack-plugin.

I'm new to vite (and to webpack too haha) and at least I couldn't find any configuration that would allow me to do something like that, is there a way to do it?

I hope you can help me c:

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert your own html/css into `index.html`? Or you want the built files to be inlined in `index.html`?

Comment: How to insert into bundled JS/CSS into existing index.html?

Comment: Yes, inject the built script from main.tsx into an html file automatically, like html-webpack-plugin does.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is [`vite-plugin-singlefile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-singlefile).